# Expressjs routes request & responses are async?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, express

I have that doubt, really is not a problem but i want to know if my actual structure to handle requests and responses is non blocking.

Some of my code looks like this:

```
get: (req, res) ->
    permission = req.user.username

    if not permission
      return res.json new Unauthorized("#{req.user.username} no tiene permisos")

    Client.find()
      .exec (err, clients) ->
        if err then res.json new Internal(err.message, err.stack)
        if not clients then res.json new NotFound('No encontrado')

        res.json new Ok(clients, 'OK')
```

And of course is handled in a router archive, but i don't exactly know when my code is async and when it's not.

So, can someone explain me if this is an async non blocking code? If it's not, please, some bit of documentation or libraries? I tryed to use promisejs but it throws me some errors in the execution (i think that's because im pretty noob).

That's all, thanks in advance!

Comment: you can actualy check if Client.find is blocking by adding console.log('found') in exec callback and console.log('before found') at the very bottom of get function. "before found" should be displayed first and when results from db gets back you should see "found"

Comment: Yes! the "before" message appears, well, before haha. So can i say that the code is async, right?

Comment: It has proven to be i quess :) nodejs didn't wait for result from db and carried on processing and that sound's async to me.

Comment: Note that if `Client.find` consisted of `process.nextTick(function(){ blockSync(); })`, then you wouldn't block in the current event loop, however you'd block in the next. This is a case that is not covered by the test suggested by @Molda .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mongoose's `exec()` is an async function in your code. As a rule of thumb, expensive operations are asynchronous, while *cheap* operations are not*. Expensive means an operation that takes some ms, such as reading a remote file, accessing a (possibly) remote database or even reading a local file. Some examples of expensive, async operations:

- [**request**](https://github.com/request/request): load a external website.
- [**fs**](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html): reading files from your system. Most of the functions are asynchronous, but as reading a file is not prohibitively expensive, they also have a synchronous version.
- [**mongoose**](http://mongoosejs.com/): as @Molda explained, your mongoose call is asynchronous. Most of the mongoose operations are.

Furthermore, asynchronous functions are characterized by them breaking the flow of the file, so they normally include a callback where the execution flow continues. In node these callbacks accept two or more arguments as a convention, being the first argument an error and the other ones the data being retrieved. Examples for the previous ones:

```
request('httsp://google.com/', function(err, response, body){
  console.log(body);   // print the website's html on the terminal
});

fs.readFile('/config.js', function(err, message){
  console.log(message);   // print the contents of config.js on the terminal
});

User.find({ id: 25 }, function(err, user){
  console.log(user);  // print user's 25 data on the terminal
});
```

Edit: as an alternative you could simplify your code by one line by including the callback in `find()`, making this function async:

```
Client.find {}, (err, clients) ->
  if err then res.json new Internal(err.message, err.stack)
  if not clients then res.json new NotFound('No encontrado')

  res.json new Ok(clients, 'OK')
```

*please note that *expensive* and *cheap* are highly relative. For instance, [parsing a huge file in JSON can be really expensive](https://github.com/nodejs/node-v0.x-archive/issues/7543) and they are synchronous, while doing a small file read is relatively cheap.